# JQuery UI draggable list cloning within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI drag and drop/sort operations i have two div sections were i'm performing drag and drop between them and sorting in my droppable container.

My issue is if i drag list contents and leave within draggable div its repeating/cloning div elements within container.

Please any help is appreciated Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/j6dqk54p/2/

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <ol id="sortable"></ol>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <ul id="draggable">
            <li>
                <div class="qitem">
                    <div>
                        <span class="question">Item1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="qitem">
                    <div>
                        <span class="question">Item2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sortable").sortable({
            revert: true,
                refreshPositions: true ,
                helper : 'clone',
                cursor: "move",
                delay: 1,
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                revert: 50
        });

        $("#sortable").disableSelection();

        $(".qitem").draggable({
            //containment : "#container",
            tolerance:"pointer",
            helper : 'clone',
            refreshPositions: true ,
            revert : 'invalid',
            opacity:.4,
        });

        $("#sortable, #draggable").droppable({
            revert:true,
            hoverClass : 'ui-state-highlight',
            greedy: true,
            refreshPositions: true,
            drop : function(ev, ui) 
            {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
                if($(this)[0].id === "sortable")
                {
                    console.log($(this).closest("button").find('.hello'));
                    $(this).find('.hello').hide();
                    $(this).find('.btn').show();
                    $(ui.draggable).draggable( 'disable' );
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean but as i understand it, you shouldn't make `#draggable` div droppable  http://jsfiddle.net/j6dqk54p/3/

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank You So Much u resolved my issue!! i'm new to stack overflow so i may not have asked my question properly Thanks for your valuable time and answer!!! one small request in draggable section can i display disabled contents on top in draggable div!! Thanks..

Comment: Like that http://jsfiddle.net/j6dqk54p/4/  ?

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank You So much u made my day Thanks a tonnnnnn!

Comment: You are welcome, have a good day then :)